# Pulling Staff list when a location is selected

Tags: active-directory

I have a requirement where when user selects the headquarters and location the staff members for working there should be automatically populated where they can be nominated for a particular task. Can anyone suggest ways to achieve this? I am a beginner and any ideas would be reall helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing code for this? Are headquarters and location your custom fields?

Comment: The head quarters and location are lookup fields in my site. I have tools to write code if it can be achieved through coding.

Comment: lookup fields to a Staff list? Or do you have UPS configured and would like to query that directly?

Comment: I think the staff are located in active directory. The HQ and location lists are provided. So when I select the HQ and location sharepoint should search the AD and return me the users working there. Sorry for my language, I am kindof a newbie here.

Comment: What is your end result? Is it to display all Staff based on those two filters? Are you using SP 2013?

Comment: yea SP 2013. The end result is when it displays the staff members working in that area, I should be able to select few members from that list and nominate them for a process.. Multiselection should be available. That is a long shot but for now I'm looking on how to get the staff members working in a location from AD

Comment: I'll show you how to setup User Profile Service which is your first step..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must setup your User Profile Service which will import all of your Active Directory entities into SharePoint. You can then create a web part which allows the end user to select from filters 'Headquarters' and 'Location' and then perform a query on the Imported user profiles:

In Central Admin:

- Make sure your service is started (UPS / UPS Sync Service under
  Manage Services on Server)
- Goto Manage Service Applications and click New  'User Profile Service Application'
- Once created, Under Synchronization click 'Configure Synchronization Connections'
- Do an IISRESET before you 'Create New Connection' or else you may get an error
- Ensure you have an account with Active Directory Read permission
- Enter your Forest Name and authorized AD account (you may need some help from an AD admin setting up permissions)
- Make sure to click populate containers and select the root or just the Users OU
- To Start the Sync click 'Start Profile Syncronization' and Select Full Sync. You should then see the Status change to 'Synchronizing'.
- Now you can 'Configure the Syncronization Timer Job' to run every Week or day depending on how often your AD is updated.

Give it some time and you will see the Number of User Profiles increase. 
Now, I suggest checking to see if the headquarters and location are stored in AD. You can confirm this by clicking 'Manage user properties'. If so, you can query the User profiles with these filters using UserProfileManager.

Comment: no probs. Good luck