# Sharepoint 2013 and Active Directoy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory

I've been asked to build a large tool on SharePoint 2013 so I've broken it down into parts and starting to learn some of the basics. I'm fairly new to SP 13 and have a little knowledge on JS but nothing to this level. Basically I need to be able to identify who the user is by looking at their active directory.

Every user would have had to sign into our office network and the tool is hosted on our internal intranet SP 13 servers.

I just need to get an idea of the code to pull the users name and display it on the screen by looking at their active directory entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a user's name as entered in AD, you can use this code:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name
```

If you're looking to do this in JS, I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20802/get-the-user-id-via-javascript) link useful. SPServices is a great library for client side async calls

If you need all the details of a user, follow this post where I describe configuring the User Profile service:

[Pulling Staff list when a location is selected](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98013/pulling-staff-list-when-a-location-is-selected/98025#98025)

Comment: Fantastic!  - I coudln't get the SPContext to work but I followed your link and it gave me all my details in a pop up - this is somethign I can work From. THANK YOU!!!